# Do i need to add the file name and extension when using FileCreationInformation

Tags: development, csom

In server-side object module i use this code to create a file at a destination folder:-

```
ListItem templetefile = null;
foreach (ListItem i in template)
{
templetefile = i;
}
byte[] fileBytes = templetefile.File.OpenBinary();
string destUrl = properties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + shareddocsList.RootFolder.Url + "/" +
                 formattedID + "/1. Order Draft/" + formattedID + " - " + customernamelabel + " - "    + titlewithoutspecialchar.Trim() + ".xlsx";
SPFile destFile = shareddocsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
```

but inside CSOM we need to use the followinf code:-

```
FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
fci.Overwrite = false;
fci.Url = destUrl;
fci.ContentStream = fs;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File destFile = currentDL.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
```

but i am not sure if the `FileCreationInformation.Url` should contain the file extension and file name as in the server-side object module case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to set the Url property.

```
//System.IO.Path.GetFileName returns the file name and extension of the specified file from given path
fci.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

Basically, you are already loading the folders where you want to add the file, so it would be okay if you just set the URL to the name of the file.

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.xlsx";
//Following would return myfile.xlsx
string onlyFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);

// Get the folder to upload into.
List shareddocsList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
ctx.Load(shareddocsList, l => l.RootFolder);
// Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
ctx.Load(shareddocsList.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now, upload the file

```
// File object.
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File destFile = null;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{  
    FileCreationInformation fci  = new FileCreationInformation();
    fci.ContentStream = fs;
    fci.Url = onlyFileName;
    fci.Overwrite = true;
    destFile = shareddocsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
    ctx.Load(destFile);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    // Return the file object for the uploaded file.
    return uploadFile;
}
```

Check [this article from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint) for more details about file upload to SharePoint.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: but inisde the `using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))` i need to pass the path of the file and not the file name,, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, in "new FileStream" you have to pass the full path of your local file.